# Not getting value on selection of row using prime faces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i am having problem on getting the value on selection of row under the table field using prime faces.
Requirement is that as i select row the associated data and relevant information must be shown on same page here like i want to show only gender and address of particular user under the table .

I am using jsf 2.0 and prime faces 3.5

here is my code please check it where i have mistaking

```
 package com.poc.faces;
all imports
.............
..............
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserManagedBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

    static {
        list.add(new User(3, "ankurjadiya", "jadiyaankur@gmail.com",
                "88849113", new Date(), "M", "sare ga ma pa"));

        list.add(new User(1, "Administrator", "admin@gmail.com", "9000510456",
                new Date(), "M", "Hyderabad"));

        list.add(new User(2, "Guest", "guest@gmail.com", "9247469543",
                new Date(), "M", "Hyderabad"));

        list.add(new User(3, "John", "John@gmail.com", "9000510456",
                new Date(), "M", "Hyderabad"));

        list.add(new User(4, "Paul", "Paul@gmail.com", "9247469543",
                new Date(), "M", "Hyderabad"));

        list.add(new User(5, "raju", "raju@gmail.com", "9000510456",
                new Date(), "M", "Hyderabad"));


    }

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String searchUser;
    private User selectedUser;
    private UserDataModel dataModel;

    public UserManagedBean() {
        this.dataModel = new UserDataModel(list);
    }

    setter and getter of fields
        ..............
        ...............

    public String login() {

        if ("ankur".equalsIgnoreCase(getUsername())
                && "ankur".equals(getPassword())) {
            return "home";
        } else {

            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

            context.addMessage("username", new FacesMessage(
                    "Invalid UserName and Password"));

            return "login";

        }
    }
```

User data model class

```
public class UserDataModel extends ListDataModel<User> implements Serializable,
        SelectableDataModel<User> {
    public UserDataModel() {

    }

    public UserDataModel(List<User> users) {
        super(users);
    }

    public User getRowData(String username) {
        List<User> list = (List<User>) getWrappedData();
        for (User user : list) {
            if (user.getUsername().equals(username))
                return user;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Object getRowKey(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return user.getUsername();
    }
}


        public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("User Selected",
                    ((User) event.getObject()).getUsername());

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }

        public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("User Unselected",
                    ((User) event.getObject()).getUsername());

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
```

This is home.xtml where i retrieving the value

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false" id="form">
        <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout"
            fullPage="true">

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" header="Menu" collapsible="true">
                <p:menu>
                    <p:submenu label="Resources">
                        <p:menuitem value="Option1"
                            action="#{userManagedBean.getSearchUsersResults()}"
                            update="left_column" />

                    </p:submenu>
                </p:menu>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <p:panel id="left_column"
                    style="width: 2px; left: 2px; margin-left: 2px">
                    <center>
                        <H1>UserData</H1>
                        <br />
                        <p:dataTable value="#{userManagedBean.dataModel}" var="user"
                            pagination="true" rows="5"  selection="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser}" selectionMode="single"    >



                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">UserId</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{user.userId}"></h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Username</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{user.username}"></h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">EmailId</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value=" #{user.emailId}"></h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Phone</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{user.phone}"></h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </center>
                </p:panel>
                <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
                    <h:outputText value="Gender:" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.gender}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Address:" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.address}" />

                </h:panelGrid>
`           </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="south" footer="bottom">

            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>

    </h:form>
</h:body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `rowKey` attribute on the `<p:dataTable/>` to properly enable row selection. The `rowKey` attribute should be set to a unique identifier for the entity in your datatable, like the primary key attribute. From your sample, it'll look something like:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{userManagedBean.dataModel}" rowKey="#{user.userId}" var="user" pagination="true" rows="5"  selection="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser}" selectionMode="single">
```